# How to get a field from a class over a soap call in php

Tags: php, soap

I have a web service running in Visual Studio 2015 with a method in it called `GetTables()`. In PHP now, I'm trying to get the response from the above method call. Here is my code in PHP:

```
<?php

$wsdl_url = 'http://localhost:1336/DisplayInfoWebService.svc?wsdl';
$client = new SOAPClient($wsdl_url);

$res = $client->GetTables();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The above PHP returns the following:

```
stdClass Object
(
[GetTablesResult] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tablename] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => alcopops
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => beers
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => ciders
                    )
             )
     )
)
```

What I'm trying to do is get those values (alcopops,beers,ciders) and parse them into a PHP array so I can use them later. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `$res->GetTablesResult->tablename` or `$res->GetTablesResult->tablename[0]->name`? Or perhaps even something like:

```
$builtArray = [];
foreach($res->GetTablesResult->tablename as $table) {
  $builtArray[] = $table->name;
}

var_dump($builtArray);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!